# difference between index and search Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm using the Data Import Handler to index a huge number of record in Solr and I'm able to index it successfully, once done I get a message like

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 14153212 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
```

But once indexing I perform a search like

```
http://localhost:9080/solr/CORENAME/elect?q=*:*
```

But I see the total number of numfound as 230101 only. Why is the difference? Does the index delete the records automatically?

Comment: Do any of your imported documents have the same ID? Maybe of the 14153212 documents, only 230101 are unique?